# ASP.NET Core 2.0 - How to populate a textbox linked to a model, depending on the selection of a dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm currently working on a Core 2.0 application.

I have a form that is linked to a model, so, when the model has data, the fields get filled with the data from the model (Using HTML tag-helpers).

Now, in that form, there is a dropdownlist, fueled by a list inside the model.
When I select an item from that dropdownlist, I would like a textbox to get the correct value of the model.

I have searched for a while, but haven't been able to find a working solution for this.

I believe using javascript would be the best way for doing it, but I'm kinda inexperienced with javascript.

Here's my form:

```
<form>
    <label asp-for="RMA.Client.Name">Client</label>
    <input asp-for="RMA.Client.Name" disabled/>
    <label asp-for="RMA.Equipament.Model"></label>
    <select asp-for="RMA.EquipamentId" asp-items="@(new 
    SelectList(Model.Equipaments,"Id","Model"))">
    </select>
    <label asp-for="RMA.Equipamento.TipoEquipamento.Tipo"></label>
    <input id="type" asp-for="RMA.Equipament.EquipmentType.Type">
</form>
```

I want the id="type" input to be filled according to the selection on the dropdownlist.

Anyone can help?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: What is `RMA.Equipament.EquipmentType`? Did `Model.Equipaments` contain the `EquipamentId` and `EquipmentType`?

Comment: RMA is a model that contains a FK to Equipment model, and also an object of type Equipment. Equipment model has a FK to EquipmentTypes.